# How can I read a normal map efficent?

Tags: c#

I wrote a code that reads an image and calculates  the normal vector for every pixel out of the RGB-Values. The Problem is even if I choose a 256x256 image c# will take too long to operate and sometimes it shuts down. Can someone show me another method or a different solution?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aufgabe17NormalMapping
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void TextManagerDelegate(string text);
    TextManagerDelegate TextHandler;

    Bitmap img;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextHandler = new TextManagerDelegate(TextManager);

    }


    public void TextManager(string txt)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(txt + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    public void RunProcess()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\USerName\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Aufgabe17NormalMapping\images.jpg";
        using (img = new Bitmap(filePath))
        {
            var height = img.Height;
            var width = img.Width;
            double[,] ArrayR = new double[width, height];
            double[,] ArrayG = new double[width, height];
            double[,] ArrayB = new double[width, height];


            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                    ArrayR[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.R.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                    ArrayG[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.G.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                    ArrayB[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.B.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                    Debug.WriteLine(ArrayR[i, j].ToString(), "Array R");
                    //Debug.Print(ArrayR[i, j].ToString(), "Array Rsdsd");
                    BeginInvoke(TextHandler, ArrayR[i, j].ToString());


                }
            }

        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task T = new Task(RunProcess);
        T.Start();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean it shuts down? Your question needs more detail for an answer.

Comment: the whole c# program freezes and it shows a message that c# can't operate any longer because the operation would take too long

Comment: @VladimirChudnofsky why do you need a `ArrayR` and others? From your question I see that this arrays are just temp objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is really fast, it is the "reporting" that takes a long time. Remove the `Debug.WriteLine` and `TextHandler` and I got the following time (in debug mode)

```
ImgSize 532x1280
Lasted: 0:00:01,181845
```

Code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    RunProcess();
    Console.WriteLine($"Lasted: {watch.Elapsed.ToString("g")}");
}

public static void RunProcess()
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Wouter\Desktop\gamez.jpg";
    using (var img = new Bitmap(filePath))
    {
        var height = img.Height;
        var width = img.Width;
        Console.WriteLine($"ImgSize {width}x{height}");

        double[,] ArrayR = new double[width, height];
        double[,] ArrayG = new double[width, height];
        double[,] ArrayB = new double[width, height];

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                ArrayR[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.R.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                ArrayG[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.G.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                ArrayB[i, j] = (((double)Convert.ToDouble(pixel.B.ToString())) + 0.5) * 2;
                str.AppendLine(ArrayR[i, j].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    BeginInvoke(TextHandler, str.ToString());
}
```

Try working with a `StringBuilder` and once you've got the entire image processed, update the UI once.

Comment: What do you mean with the `StringBuilder`? Can you please show me how to use the `StringBuilder`and how to update the UI?

Comment: Updated. When using `File.WriteAllText(@"colors.txt", str.ToString());`, It took 1.5 seconds for the 532x1280 image. (68k lines)

Comment: @VladimirChudnofsky @Laoujin gave you a good hint, I think you should lookup `StringBuilders` by yourself before asking how to use it.